# Multilingual Forms possible with Infopath or Nintex?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, custom-form, language, multilingual

I have setup a multilingual site, which works perfectly fine so far. But now I hit a roadblock with editing list forms.

For translation of column names and descriptions I follow this [method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff800886(v=office.14)#adding-translations-to-user-resources). Basically I do the whole setup in English, enable another language on that site and open it in a browser, that is set to that language. Now I can edit all column names and descriptions and it will only show it in the respective language.

So when it comes to forms, they will be either in English or in one of my translated languages, when the user´s browser is set to that language. Perfect!

Unfortunately editing forms has become a nightmare with SharePoint Designer, so I was happy to see InfoPath still around and also our license for Nintex forms. But both tools share one nig downsite, my current roadblock.

I do not have any other specific knowledge about internal column name handling. But I can observe, that InfoPath and Nintex do not use the same reference like the default forms. While they show my translation perfectly fine, InfoPath will always have the english names und Nintex will take your current editing language… Damn!

Does anyone has a way around this? I would even go for coding my own forms, if I could only find a nice tutorial for that mess…

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Nintex Forms I can suggest two options :

1. You can create lookup function to dynamically adjust controls : reference [here](http://www.sharepointpub.com/nintex-forms-multi-language-form/) or [here](http://vadimtabakman.com/nintex-forms-multilingual-form.aspx)
2. You can double all the labels in your form and play with rules to hide and show switch default user languages

Comment: Thanks, Ahmed. Unfortunately the first link is dead for me and the second one is too heavy on coding. There is link to some other solution, but that is dead as well. I think, I would go for second solution anyway. If there is really no possibility to get the ootb solution of SharePoint running in Nintex or InfoPath.